How to update first element in array object or insert when array does not exist
How to update first element in array object or insert when array does not exist
My document is
{
  _id: 1,
  age: "young",
  hobby: [
  {
    vehicle: "car",
    velocity: "fast"
  },
  {
    vehicle: "motorcycle",
    velocity: "fast"
  }
  ]
}

My goal is: when age became old, first hobby became "slow" but others remain "fast"
My code is:
mongoTemplate.updateFirst(
  Query.query(where("_id").is("1")),
    Update.update("age", "old")
      .set("hobby.0.velocity", "slow"), "collection name")

Result is ok.
{
  _id: 1,
  age: "old",
  hobby: [
  {
    vehicle: "car",
    velocity: "slow" 
  },
  {
    vehicle: "motorcycle",
    velocity: "fast"
  }
  ]
}

But sometimes hobby in not initialized:
{
  _id: 1,
  age: "young"
}

and after update result is wrong, because hobby became map, not a list

{
  "_id": 1111,
  "age": "old",
  "hobby": {
    "0": {
      "velocity": "slow"
    }
  }
}

Is is possible to get achieve in such case a hobby as a list?
{
  _id: 1,
  age: "old",
  hobby: [
    {
      velocity: "slow" 
    }
  ]
}


Is it possible for hobby to be initialised (exists) but null? Like { _id: 1, age: "young", hobby: null } ? What about as an empty array hobby: [] ?

If hobby = [], it works. I hobby = null, 'Cannot create field '0' in element {hobby: null}'

This update pipeline is more complex than the previous related answer, to handle the additional cases of:

Missing hobby field

{ _id: 1, age: "young" }


Hobby being set to null

{ _id: 1, age: "young", hobby: null }


Hobby being an empty array

{ _id: 1, age: "young", hobby: [] }



Notes:

The first param of $ifNull handles hobby being present and non-empty.

It will evaluate to null for hobby being an empty array and then use the fallback expression


The second param of $ifNull sets hobby to an array with a single object [{ "velocity": "slow" }]

db.collection.update({ _id: 1 },
[
  {
    $set: {
      "age": "old",
      "hobby": {
        $ifNull: [
          // set the first object's velocity to slow
          // if it doesn't exist, or is null, or is an empty array
          // then this will be null and use the fallback expression
          {
            $concatArrays: [
              [
                {
                  $mergeObjects: [
                    { $arrayElemAt: ["$hobby", 0] },
                    // set velocity to slow for the first object
                    { "velocity": "slow" }
                  ]
                }
              ],
              {
                $slice: [
                  "$hobby",
                  1,
                  {
                    // use size=1 when hobby is an empty array []
                    $max: [{ $size: "$hobby" }, 1]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          // new hobby when missing
          [{ "velocity": "slow" } ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])

Mongo Playground
